# unable to re-loop through a while loop successfully

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

my goal in the following code is to keep getting guesses until the user either guesses the right number, or quit. To quit, I am able to easily break out of my loops, but when I try to continue in my loops, it doesn't work right. First it requires multiple inputs, and then also entirely regenerates my number, while what I want to do is to keep getting guesses (asking user) for the SAME random number.
Below is my code:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count, randNum, guess;
    count = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        System.out.println("Guess a number b/w 1 and 100");
        guess = scan.nextInt();
        count += 1;

        if (guess == randNum) {
            System.out.println("Correct guess.");
            System.out.println("It took " + count + " tries to guess the right number");
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? ");
            System.out.println("Press any letter to play again or q to quit: ");
            if (scan.next().charAt(0) == 'q' || scan.next().charAt(0) == 'Q') {
                break;
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (guess > randNum) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is bigger than actual number. Would you like to try again?");
            System.out.println("Press q to quit or any other letter to try again");
            if (scan.next().charAt(0) == 'q' || scan.next().charAt(0) == 'Q') {
                break;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (guess < randNum) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is smaller than actual number. Would you like to try again?");
            System.out.println("Press q to quit or any other letter to try again");
            if (scan.next().charAt(0) == 'q' || scan.next().charAt(0) == 'Q') {
                break;
            }
            else  {
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }

}
```

}

Comment: talk about a moving target - randNum is being re-set on each iteration of the loop

Comment: You need to separate games and attempts into outer/inner loops.

Answer (score 1):

The code for generating the random number should be before the while statement. When you call `continue`, it goes back to the first line of the while block and consequently generates another random number.

Comment: thanks for the help. It did fix that issue, but now there is one more issue. When I enter a letter to continue, I have to enter about 3 times before the loop restarts. I am not understanding why that is

Answer (score 1):

Your statement declaring the int randNum is inside of the while loop, so every time the while loop repeats, the number is declared (again) and set to a value between 1 and 100.

If you want to prevent this, declare the variable and initialize it with a random value outside of the while loop.

A small side note: by initializing the variable inside of the while loop, you are limiting its scope more than you probably want to. Every time it loops through, the previous randNum you created no longer exists, and it then creates a new one. Basically, if you want it to be more permanent, initialize it outside of the loop.

Also, if you only want it to ask for a number between 1 and 100 the very first time, move it outside of the loop. This however is up to you on whether or not you want it to ask each time, or just once.

```
//…
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count, randNum, guess;
    count = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
    System.out.println("Guess a number b/w 1 and 100");            
    while (true) {
        /*Random rand = new Random();
        randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        System.out.println("Guess a number b/w 1 and 100");*/

        guess = scan.nextInt();
        count += 1;
        //…
```